# Referring child nodes in allOf if then condition in parent node

Tags: json, jsonschema

```
    {
   "$schema":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
   "$id":"PersonalDetails.json",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "Header":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "HeaderName":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "HeaderValue":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "Details":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "FName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "LName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "Address":{
                  "type":"object",
                  "properties":{
                     "FlatNo":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "Sector":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "LandMarks":{
                        "type":"object",
                        "properties":{
                           "LandMark1":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "LandMark2":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "required":[
                     "Sector"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}



{
   "Header":{
      "HeaderName":"DummyName",
      "HeaderValue":"DummyName"
   },
   "Details":[
      {
         "FName":"Chicago",
         "LName":"Laos",
         "Address":{
            "FlatNo":"Excalibur",
            "Sector":"07",
            "LandMarks":{
               "LandMark1":"USA",
               "LandMark2":"UK"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So the requirement is to insert IF then conditions in Json Schema with following conditions

1. if LandMark1 = USA   and   FlatNo = Excalibur
   then Sector is required

I am not able to figure out where exactly should i place this condition and its syntax

i tried using $ref in if then conditions in allOf in Details as its parent for both Address and LandMarks
but even that didn't work as it was not able to figure out reference

Any help is highly apprecitiable

Comment: The object `LandMarks` should have `properties`. It would be good if you could show what you have tried regarding `$ref`, as then we might be able to help fix the problem.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry i guess i missed the properties
In details allOf i just added If then conditions nothing else.
if you still want i can update,

Comment: No problem. I suggest updating your question content. Yes, please update to show what you tried so far, and I can likely help =]

Comment: Hi,
i have updated the json schema
I didn't do the updates which i was trying, as that was just not correct.
so if you can start with some fresh approach that would be better

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `if`/`then` keywords to describe this. The hard part is the `if` schema.

You need to define an `if` schema that will validate to true when given an instance where your conditions are met. It can help to develop this schema separately and then add it to your full schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "FlatNo": { "const": "Excalibur" },
    "LandMarks": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "LandMark1": { "const": "USA" }
      },
      "required": ["LandMark1"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["LandMarks", "FlatNo"]
}
```

The following instance would pass validation against that schema. It would fail if FlatNo != Excalibur or LandMark1 != USA.

```
{
  "FlatNo":"Excalibur",
  "Sector":"07",
  "LandMarks":{
    "LandMark1":"USA",
    "LandMark2":"UK"
  }
}
```

Now it should be trivial to apply `if`/`then` to your address schema.

```
"if": { ... schema from above ... },
"then": { "required": ["Sector"] }
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for your inputs. Just out of curosity can we have if/then for the following condition:-
if LandMark1 = "USA" and Sector = "07"
    then LandMark2 is required
but instead of placing it in address schema can i place it in LandMarks schema itself

Comment: JSON Schema can't look up the JSON tree. So, you need to put the `if`/`then` high enough that it can "see" all of the elements it needs to set constraints on. If it's in the "Landmarks" schema, the `if` would have no way to set the "Sector = 07" constraint.

Comment: Ok, got it Jason. I tried to put the if else condition on Address level but it's still not working. I suspect that the syntax might be wrong. So it will be really helpful if you can share the if-then conditions which i need to place on address level

Comment: A comment isn't a great place to share a schema. I think the best way for me to help is if you create a new question and post what you've tried and isn't working for you.

Comment: Hi, Jason. Uploaded a new question kindly help me out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205386/how-to-refer-child-attribute-in-required-of-parent-level

Comment: In present scenario we have if  LandMark1 = USA and FlatNo = Excalibur then LandMark2 is required, so there's a AND operator can you please help me with the syntaxes with OR operator.Thanks!!