# How to refer child attribute in required of parent level

Tags: json, jsonschema

```
{
   "$schema":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
   "$id":"PersonalDetails.json",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "Header":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "HeaderName":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "HeaderValue":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "Details":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "FName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "LName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "Address":{
                  "type":"object",
                  "properties":{
                     "FlatNo":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "Sector":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "LandMarks":{
                        "type":"object",
                        "properties":{
                           "LandMark1":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "LandMark2":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "required":[
                     "Sector"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Example Data:

```
    {
       "Header":{
          "HeaderName":"DummyName",
          "HeaderValue":"DummyName"
       },
       "Details":[
          {
             "FName":"Chicago",
             "LName":"Laos",
             "Address":{
                "FlatNo":"Excalibur",
                "Sector":"07",
                "LandMarks":{
                   "LandMark1":"USA",
                   "LandMark2":"UK"
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

This is the approach I tried

```
"allOf":[
   {
      "if":"properties":{
         "FlatNo":{
            "const":"07"
         },
         "LandMarks":{
            "properties":{
               "LandMark1":{
                  "const":"USA"
               }
            },
            "then":"LandMarks":{
               "required":[
                  "LandMark2"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
```

So the requirement is to insert IF then conditions in JSON Schema with following conditions

if LandMark1 = USA and FlatNo = Excalibur then LandMark2 is required
I am not able to figure out where exactly should I place this condition and its syntax

I tried if-then condition for LandMarks on parent level but somehow even that was not working.

Any help is highly appreciable

Comment: Can you show us what you tried that didn't work? As a separate schema is fine and preferable. Should be able to help you here no problem. Can't tell what you did wrong unless I can see exactly what you tried =]

Comment: i tried placing if-then condition in allOf tag in the Address level in above schema but even that approach was not working

Comment: I understand, but I would still like to see what this looked like. Please can you edit your question to include this? =]

Comment: Hi Relequestual, I have edited the question and you can see the approach which i tried

Comment: Thanks. It's not quite proper JSON there. It looks like your `if` and `then` are not part of the same object. Do you want to tidy that up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure where you had the schema fragment you updated your question with, but here's a fully fixed schema based on that fragment...

You have to nest `properties` from the furthest up the tree in the JSON instance that you want the condition and resulting applied subschema to have context with.

Here's a live demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/6VwCt

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Details": {
      "items": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "Address": {
                  "properties": {
                    "FlatNo": {
                      "const": "07"
                    },
                    "LandMarks": {
                      "properties": {
                        "LandMark1": {
                          "const": "USA"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "then": {
              "properties": {
                "Address": {
                  "properties": {
                    "LandMarks": {
                      "required": [
                        "LandMark2"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've assumed in your example data you got `FlatNo` and `Sector` mixed up, so I've corrected that in the live demo instance.

Here is what the schema fragment would look like at the `Address` level...

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Address": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "FlatNo": {
                "const": "07"
              },
              "LandMarks": {
                "properties": {
                  "LandMark1": {
                    "const": "USA"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "LandMarks": {
                "required": [
                  "LandMark2"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any chance we can place this if-then in Address level rather than putting in Details allOf

Comment: Sure you can. let me know if you get stuck doing this. It looks like you just didn't think about how the values of `if` and `then` are subschemas, so you still need to use `properties`.

Comment: keeping in mind the above schema i tried to write it for Address level also, but getting stuck on it. Can you please give the schema for Address level too

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this. I think you were close! The values of `if` and `then` are JSON Schemas in their own right, so you needed to use `properties` again to target the value of an object.

Comment: If you have multiple conditional checks, there is something else you will need to, but you haven't expressed such in your question.

Comment: In present scenario we have if  LandMark1 = USA and FlatNo = Excalibur then LandMark2 is required, so there's a AND operator can you please help me with the syntaxes with OR operator.Thanks!!

Comment: The value of `if` is a subschema. A JSON Schema itself. You need to define all of the conditions within that subschema that you want to meet in order to trigger the `then` subschema.

Comment: Yup, that is correct but with OR operator I am not able to visualize the syntax and hence if you can provide an example or use above statement that would be really helpful

Comment: I'd suggest asking a fresh question with a minimal example. It looks like my answer did provide you with a solution for the question you asked. (You should also mark my answer as accepted if it solved the question.) Questions are most helpful to others when they don't change after getting a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for response added question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883437/how-to-specify-or-condition-in-if-else-json-schema any help will be highly appreciated