# How to specify OR condition in If else json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Please refer this link for schema and data

[How to refer child attribute in required of parent level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205386/how-to-refer-child-attribute-in-required-of-parent-level/66206472?noredirect=1#comment123527236_66206472)

In the above example requirement is to insert IF then conditions in JSON Schema with following conditions

if LandMark1 = USA and FlatNo = Excalibur then LandMark2 is required
But now I am trying to think of a way to change the AND operator to OR.

Any help with the syntactical change for OR will be helpful

Comment: Can both be true or is it an exclusive OR? Have you looked at the `oneOf` and `anyOf` keywords?

Comment: Yes both can be true or any one of it can be true.i did try out any of method but I was not confident as I was not able to visualize the syntax changes

Answer (score 0):

As both can be true, or just one, you need to use `anyOf` under your `if` condition.

> This keyword's value MUST be a non-empty array.  Each item of the
> array MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> An instance validates successfully against this keyword if it
> validates successfully against at least one schema defined by this
> keyword's value.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.2.1.2

I've demonstrated this using a partial from your schema.
You will need to add the second subschema.

Each item in the `anyOf` array is a schema itself.

```
{
  "$schema":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "if": {
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "properties":{
          "LandMark1":{
            "const":"USA"
          }
        }
      },
      {Condition_two_subschema for flatNo excalibur}
    ]
  },
  "then": true,
  "else": false
}
```

Comment: In the previous example we placed if else in allOf can we we store it in that way so that we can have chain of if then . I tried but the condition are not working

Comment: Yes, you can, but they are not a chain of if/then/else. All subschemas in an `allOf` are equal.